# Azure Search data.count does not match document count

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We can query the Azure Search document count in multiple ways.

1) Via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-index-statistics
2) Via the Search Explorer in the Azure Portal by searching for "$count=true"

We get very different results. In our case it is:
1) "documentCount": 153655
2) "@odata.count": 331913

Do these values depict different things in the index? Clearly they are very different, but we aren't sure what we are seeing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in the Index Statistics API that we’ve already fixed and the fix is being rolled out globally as we speak. We should finish by the end of the week. Apologies for the inconvenience.